# Move anchor point of hyperref

Tags: hyperref, anchor

In this LateX template :
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book
there are automatic pdf bookmarks that allow the reader to jump from part I to part II for example in Adobe Acrobat. It also works from the ToC, with hyperref links, if one clicks on "Part One". However, it seems that the anchor point of part pages falls in the middle of the page, which is not very elegant. I would prefer that the link points to the top of the part page, where the title is actually displayed. How can I modify this behaviour, i.e. move the anchor point?

Edit: maybe the fact that I used this template as an example for my issue was clumsy. I indeed first noticed this problem with this template, but still it happens in much simpler cases. See MWE :

```latex
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
{\vspace{-8cm}\titlerule[5pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{1pc}\huge\MakeUppercase}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{My first part}

\chapter{A Nice title}

\lipsum[5]

\chapter{An other nice title}

\lipsum[3]

\part{My second part}

\chapter{Amazing title}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

By default, the title of the part is centered so the link points toward this position. If the title is moved (upwards in my MWE), the link won't follow the title and still point to the middle of the page. In a more general case, if one uses titlesec to obtain a custom fancy part page, I guess the hyperref link will keep pointing to the middle of the page, which is, as I said, not very elegant. Is there a way to correct it?

Comment: well as the page said: they are offering a paid service to adapt the template. So why don't you ask them?

Comment: My goal was not to use this community to obtain a custom template, of course. See my edited version.

Comment: Oh titlesec. Well obviously your \vspace{-8cm} moves the title before the anchor, but debugging (and adapting) titlesec is imho rather painful. I wouldn't use it to create such "page headings".